# Disable Element If

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a pretty straightforward library function I've got here. I've had to build it in to about 3 different forms but I never heard of this kind of function anywhere else.

I'm trying to make it as readable and clear as possible, but I also am not too familiar with the best way to capture values in JavaScript. As far as I know, the following `disableChecker` function allows me to capture the value arguments at declaration time so I can have many of these `DisableIf` checks going simultaneously.

```
    function disableChecker(checkSelector, disableValue, targetSelector) {
        var optionValue = $(checkSelector).val();
        if (optionValue === disableValue) {
            $(targetSelector).prop("disabled", true); //Disable target
        } else {
            $(targetSelector).prop("disabled", false); //Enable target
        }
    }
    function DisableIf(checkSelector, disableValue, targetSelector) {
        $(checkSelector).on("change,keyup,blur", disableChecker(checkSelector, disableValue, targetSelector));
    }
```

Usage:

```
<select id="disableSource">
    <option value="0">Disable Next</option>
    <option value="1">Enable Next</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="disableTarget" />
<input type="text" id="disableTarget2" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Please note that at this time, order is important!
    DisableIf("#disableSource", "0", "#disableTarget");
    DisableIf("#disableTarget", "Disable Next", "#disableTarget2");
    DisableIf("#disableSource", "0", "#disableTarget2");
<script>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vd0ezfcd/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Readability:**

Merging code into a single line:

- **Variables** - If the function isn't too complex to understand, variable declarations that are only used in a single location are unnecessary.
- **If-statements** - If-Statements take a boolean and do something different based on the boolean. If you're toggling a value like "disabled" you usually can just pass the boolean straight to the value-setter.

  ```
  function disableChecker(checkSelector, disableValue, targetSelector) {
       $(targetSelector).prop("disabled", $(checkSelector).val() === disableValue);
  }
  ```

**Library:**

- **Naming** - It should be clear-er to anyone working with the code what each function does (whether this person be you, someone else, or you 6 months from now).
- **Condition** - Why force it to always be an equality condition? Perhaps in the future you may want it to be greater-than or something even more complex? By passing in a boolean parameter instead you expand your library function's potential.
- **Maintainability** - Single Responsibility Principal. Each function does one specific thing so that if any of the parts change they aren't all affected.
- **Initialization** - This is the only slight down-side that I see. It takes a little bit more code turning the condition into a parameter. But flexibility and readability usually come at some kind of cost (generally in the setup or performance departments). Given that it's a library function though, you're probably wanting that flexibility.

Something like:

```
function setDisable(targetSelector, isDisabled) {
    $(targetSelector).prop("disabled", isDisabled);   
}

function valueEqualsExpected(selector, expectedValue) {
    return $(selector).val() === expectedValue;
}

function turnOnAndRunEvent(events, selector, func) {
    $(selector).on(events, func);
    //$(document).on(events, selector, func);
    func();
}

turnOnAndRunEvent("change keyup blur", "#disableSource", function () {
    setDisable("#disableTarget", valueEqualsExpected("#disableSource", "0"));
});
turnOnAndRunEvent("change keyup blur", "#disableTarget", function () {
    setDisable("#disableTarget2", valueEqualsExpected("#disableTarget", "Disable Next"));
});
turnOnAndRunEvent("change keyup blur", "#disableSource", function () {
    setDisable("#disableTarget2", valueEqualsExpected("#disableSource", "0"));
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1hps7fm/)